# Is it lawful for naturopaths to present themselves as doctors in the US and Canada?

Tags: united-states, canada, medical

Some naturopaths put "Dr." in their title (without completing a medical or any other doctoral degree). Is that legal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the title Ph.D. or Dr. meaningless in the sense that anyone can use it?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46501/is-the-title-ph-d-or-dr-meaningless-in-the-sense-that-anyone-can-use-it) (PS You haven't mentioned whether the naturopaths in question have completed a doctoral degree other than an MD, or not)

Comment: This has no relation to academia.

Comment: Migrating on OP's request.

Comment: This varies by state (in the US) and province (in Canada). See http://www.kyena.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Dr.-Title-Protection-Laws-April-2013.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I know of no legal restrictions on using the title of *Doctor* in the United states. I know next to nothing about Canadian law and can't speak on that.

Falsely claiming to have a license to practice medicine is probably illegal, depending on circumstances, and practicing medicine without a license is most certainly illegal, and there a numerous federal and state laws that would apply. But simply styling one's self as *Dr.* is unlikely to be held by a court as a claim to hold a medical license, or a particular degree.

It's, of course, misleading and generally frowned to use the *Dr.* prefix unless one has earned an MD or PhD. Some holders of honorary doctorates use it as well, though some debate whether that's acceptable or not.

Comment: This (the claim about misleading and frowned on) is actually not true, since there are many other doctorates – DDS, OD, Ed. D, DBA, DSc., DA, DEng, Th. D etc. The problem is that there is also a Doctor of Naturopathic Medicine, where the degree officially contains the trigger word "Doctor".